# How to unfold code one level at a time in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, code-formatting, code-folding

Let's say I have a class, some subclasses in it (in Ruby, for example), some methods in them etc.. In ST2 I choose `Edit -> Code Folding -> Fold all`. When I click the small arrow next to the class name I want to see the class body, but the methods in them still folded, so that I can unfold them one by one. Currently, ST2 does not behave like that, as clicking an arrow unfolds all sublevels. Do you know a way to unfold each folded item without affecting its subitems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do exactly what I want. The workaround is to fold to a particular level, then unfold all, then fold to one level below the previous one, unfold all etc., etc.